# UIImagePickerController get video length before compression

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I need to get the video length before the compression happens cos I need to restrict my video length to a maximum time interval. When I click on a video the compression happens first and after that only it calls didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. So if its a larger video file there is no point of making user wait to do the video size validation. Isn't there any way to make it prior to didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing and not having much luck either allowing trimming or limiting the length of videos selected before compression happens.

Comment: No luck with it. I kept the functionality as its cos its the default which offers in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are letting them record, you can cap the length of video capture with `videoMaximumDuration`.

I believe it also applies to the Library, but not sure.

Comment: Yes I already added that. I use it to allow user to trim the video. But prior to that before compressing I would like to give an alert to user mentioning that it will exceed the maximum limit.

Comment: I thought `allowsEditing` allows the user to trim. `videoMaximumDuration` should cap the length.

Comment: This is true for recording but I also need to select larger videos from photo library.